# How are Penrose diagrams derived?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, topology, causality

How are Penrose diagrams derived?

[image: Penrose diagrams]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f0/PENROSE2.PNG))</sub>

Comment: More on Penrose diagrams: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41725/2451